# Application crashs as soon as I click register

Tags: java, android

Trace:

```
04-23 18:21:28.380: D/dalvikvm(628): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 48K, 4% free 6396K/6595K, paused 76ms
04-23 18:21:28.390: I/dalvikvm-heap(628): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.797MB for 513744-byte allocation
04-23 18:21:28.520: D/dalvikvm(628): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 6894K/7111K, paused 81ms
04-23 18:21:28.660: D/dalvikvm(628): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 6894K/7111K, paused 4ms+13ms
04-23 18:22:09.350: D/AndroidRuntime(628): Shutting down VM
04-23 18:22:09.350: W/dalvikvm(628): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:368)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:208)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:431)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:901)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:42)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:61)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.example.AndroidLoginAndRegistration.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:55)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-23 18:22:09.370: E/AndroidRuntime(628):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 18:22:12.530: I/Process(628): Sending signal. PID: 628 SIG: 9
```

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;

public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

// Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp
// use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function get Login status
 * */
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Reset Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}
```

The logcat output can be found at the top. Below that is the code for my user function which doesn't work despite my best efforts. I have tried changing the URL to localhost among other things, but instead of saving the data to xampp it crashes. I have the JSONParse and DataBaseHandler in library bits, but I can't figure out where the problem is. Even the login page simply crashes rather than showing an error message. I have ensured that all required php files are present.

Comment: post [logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) dump

Comment: i have posted logcat stuff aswell now...

Comment: "You are attempting to perform a network operation on the main thread." [Developer's Guide.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) I would guess you have to move it to an AsyncTask, run it in the background, etc...

Comment: can you please tell me how can i do it?? :)

Comment: It must be crashing on this line, try surrounding a try catch exception e and print what you can from the exception object. I'm looking at documentation now. JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);

Answer (score 0):

[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

> This is only thrown for applications targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged

Android has added a [DownloadFilesTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You'll need to use the DownloadFilesTask.

```
 private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
 private private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/"; //remove other one
 protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
     List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     for(int i=0; i<params.length; i+=2){ //increment i by length of pair(2)
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(params[i], params[i+1])); 
     }
     return jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

Modify your Login function. From this

```
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}
```

To this

```
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    String[] params = {"tag", login_tag, "email", email, "password", password};
    JSONObject json = new LoginTask().execute(params);
    return json;
}
```

It's a little hack, you're pressed for time. You'll have to do something similar for each function with it's own task. You could make it more modular if the first parameter in the string array is the function that you want to do. Then have the download task use some branches to determine what URL to pass to the function getJSONFromUrl.

Comment: and and if you dont mind can mail you the seperate project just with these things so you can have a look aswell ??? :)

Comment: give me some time to make an example proj

Comment: Are you doing the parameters over http post or get?

Comment: THAnk you very much as i am really greatful to u as i am doing it for my uni project :o and im just a bignner i am try to login and register through php &mysql

Comment: look at this as i was trying this and i followed each and every step but couldnt make it work....http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: I would post on the comments and ask the guy who wrote the blog. I will be following this tutorial later in the week for the learning experience. The error may be something copy pasted incorrectly somewhere through the layers of his code. The author is doing a pretty good job helping people in his comments.

Comment: Yep yep yep!! but the thing is this is the only thing im strugling with as i gotta submit my assignment soon... :o you try it and see if you can figure something out or get it working???

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html If you followed everything correctly, all you need to do is make the function call asynchronous. Copy paste the code from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html and change the parameters

Comment: I've made some edits. I can't guarantee it will work the first time because I don't have the entire project and the server running. But you need to move the networking logic off the UI thread

Comment: Justin i am having too many error for some as i dont have Login task in my classes :o So as you created it as if you dont mind can you mail me zip folder so i can see what you have really done as i am getting bit confused now.... I am really sorry to bother and waste your time on it.....:) and even with the loginURL thing i got this error "Duplicate modifier for the field loginURL"

Comment: You'll have to add the LoginTask class as a private class to the Android activity class.

Comment: My email is my stack overflow username @gmail.com but I don't have time to look at it all right now. If you downgrade the version of the the app from HoneyComb to 2.3, the program should work.

Answer (score 0):

You are running network operations on the main thread. At least in ICS this is not allowed and you get that exception. I had the same issue while developing an application for Android 2.3.3 where it was fine but was crashing on 4.0.3.

I can't provide you a modified code as your approach must make some significant changes. You must run the functions for login and register on another  thread and don't know how you invoke them. It would be easy to create a thread in each of them but returning the result from the method would not be possible.

The right implementation is to run them on a different thread and notify the main thread when the result is obtained. One method to send the notification is using a Handler that is passed to the newly created thread. I found an example here: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/progressbar-updating-using-message-handler